# How to connect to Microsoft SQL Server via forwarded ports?

Tags: sql-server, portforwarding

I've forwarded the ports, which SQL Server is using, from my local machine to the machine where SQL Server is running

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=1433 connectaddress=192.168.1.110 connectport=1433
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=1434 connectaddress=192.168.1.110 connectport=1434
```

Then I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the Database with the IP Adress 192.168.1.110, which is working fine.

Trying to connect to localhost, or localhost,1433 (mind the comma, instead the colon), does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.